# PHP get the last 3 elements of an associative array while preserving the keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
[13] => Array
        (
            [0] => joe
            [1] => 0

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => bob
            [1] => 0
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => sue
            [1] => 0
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => john
            [1] => 0
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => harry
            [1] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => larry
            [1] => 0
        )
```

How can I get the last 3 elements while preserving the keys? (the number of elements in the array may vary, so I cannot simply slice after the 2nd element)

So the output would be:

```
  [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => john
            [1] => 0
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => harry
            [1] => 0
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => larry
            [1] => 0
        )
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

If you want to preserve key, you can pass in true as the fourth argument:

```
array_slice($a, -3, 3, true);
```

Comment: Would like to note, that you do not need to know the length of the array for this to work as intended. So it will return the maximum amount specified, or less if your array length is less, without an error.  https://3v4l.org/v2HLV

Answer (score 45):

Use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$res = array_slice($array, -3, 3, true);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `array_slice` with offset as `-3` so you don't have to worry about the array length also by setting `preserve_keys` parameter to `TRUE`.

```
$arr = array_slice($arr,-3,3,true);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
<?php
    // -3 = start from the end
    // true = preserve_keys
    $result = array_slice($array, 0, -3, true); 
?>
```

Comment: This does not do what is required. A negative integer on the third parameter means "stop this many elements before the end of the array". This will return the first n-3 elements, where n is the total number of elements in the array.