# Select first or last character groups from string with period separators

Tags: php, string

I am asking help with php code to manipulate a string that I am retrieving from an SQL database.  The string is in this format:  Groups of 3-5 alphanumerics separated by periods.  The number of alphanumeric groups in the string is quite variable (from 1 - 20 or more groups).

- *Example 1:  J89.NEWTT.IIU.MZZ.OXI.*
- *Example 2:  ORD6.BAE.J89.DLH.YRL.N5500.W9700.NUGSM.N6500.*

I need to do 2 things with these:

1. separate into a new string just the **first 3 groups** between periods (in Example 1, results would be "J89.NEWTT.IIU")
2. separate into a new string just the **last 3 groups** between periods (in Example 2, results would be "W9700.NUGSM.N6500")

I'm having trouble getting the usual players to work with this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why `regex` ? $chunks = explode('.','J89.NEWTT.IIU.MZZ.OXI');

Comment: explode('.','J89.NEWTT.IIU.MZZ.OXI')

Comment: thanks, removed regex, and yes explode it is.  thanks.

Comment: Thanks:   **$chunk=explode....; $result = array_slice($chunk,-3,3); implode(".",$result);** works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Split it (`explode`), slice out the parts you want, then join them back together with `.` again.

This is a strange format and picking the first/last three chunks seems really arbitrary.  Is it structured data?  If so, why are you storing it in a single field in your database?

Comment: Agree.  Explode seems best, and is easy to manage when rejoining *first 3*.  Just not sure how to select the last 3 groups for rejoining (after exploding) when there can be any number of alphanumberic groups.

Comment: To explain the data... it's aircraft routes, also associated with flight numbers, latitudes, longitudes, and a variety of other data.  This chunk is the aircraft route provided in this format by another server.  In some cases, I need to deliver the first 3 points after departure, in some cases the last 3 points prior to arrival .... if that explanation helps.

Comment: why don't you have another table with a column for each of flight number, origin, destination, whatever, etc.?  you're kinda defeating the purpose of using a database.  also, [last three elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468912/php-get-the-last-3-elements-of-an-array) has come up verbatim before

Comment: Perhaps.  Trying to work in someone else's DB system.  But may be best to branch some data off into another DB.  Thanks for the link.  Searched hard, but guess my stack-overflow-fu bad today.  Sorry, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks again, Evee & Ubercooluk:   **$chunk=explode....; $result = array_slice($chunk,-3,3); implode(".",$result);** works like a charm.