# PHP Combine arrays with the same ID

Tags: php

I have $row which outputs the below. Array 0 - 4 do not change per user but the last items in each array need to be added together.

```
array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => 'Joe',
  2 => 'Bloggs',
  3 => 'joe.bloggs@mail.com',
  4 => '1,2',
  5 => 1,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 1,
)array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => 'Joe',
  2 => 'Bloggs',
  3 => 'joe.bloggs@mail.com',
  4 => '1,2',
  5 => 0,
  6 => 1,
  7 => 1,
)array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => 'Jane',
  2 => 'Doe',
  3 => 'jane.doe@mail.com',
  4 => '1,4',
  5 => 1,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 1,
)array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => 'Jane',
  2 => 'Doe',
  3 => 'jane.doe@mail.com',
  4 => '1,4',
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
)
```

I need to combine them so they are like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Joe
    [2] => Bloggs
    [3] => joe.bloggs@mail.com
    [4] => 1,2
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Jane
    [2] => Doe
    [3] => jane.doe@mail.com
    [4] => 1,4
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 1
)
```

My code so far is:

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($row as $item) {
    if (!array_key_exists($item[0], $combined)) {
        $combined[$item[0]] = $item;
    } else {
        
        array_push($combined, $item);
    }   
}
```

But this is not doing what I expect. Not really sure where to go with this so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP get the last 3 elements of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468912/php-get-the-last-3-elements-of-an-array)

Comment: @BurhanKashour That is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Fazberry Your solution doesn't even try to sum up the values, you just keep replacing the item with the latest one. Also, when you do `array_push`, the element is inserted at the next available index. Your check is based on the index being the same as the user's id. If you want to go that way, then scrap the push and insert manually at the desired index (basically, your `if` branch contents should be in the `else` branch, and the `if` branch should do the addition).

Comment: @FazBerry can you paste your array here instead of that printed so we can easily plug it

Comment: @jerson not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @FazBerry paste your valid array with variable so we can easy plug it instead of writing each 1by1

Comment: `var_export` allows you to create a _code_ representation of your array, so please replace the debug output you have shown abve with that, so that we can easily copy&paste this to have a working array without having to go throught too much extra trouble. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Comment: Hi @CBroe updated array above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. You simply needed to add the values.

```
/**
 * @param array $combined       the combined array
 * @param array $item           a single row of data (8-element array)
 *
 * @returns array               the updated combined array
 */
function combineArray(array $combined, array $item) {
    // This is how we know whether the element exists or not
    $key = $item[0];
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $combined)) {
        // This is a NEW item, so just add it to the combined array.
        $combined[$key] = $item;
    } else {
        // This already exists. Modify the required columns.
        $combined[$key][5] += $item[5];
        $combined[$key][6] += $item[6];
        $combined[$key][7] += $item[7];
        /*
           You could also do this automatically from the type of variable, instead of specifying 5, 6 and 7:
           foreach ($item as $i => $value) {
               if (in_array(gettype($value), array('integer', 'float'))) {
                   $combined[$key][$i] += $value;
               }
           }
        */
    }   

    return $combined;
}

$combined = array();

foreach ($row as $item) {
    $combined = combineArray($combined, $item);
}
// Now convert to "true" array. This is VERY IMPORTANT if you want to output
// it to, say, JSON, where [ 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b' ] and [ 0 => 'a', 2 => 'b' ]
// are two different KINDS of object (the first an array, the second a dict)

$combined = array_values($combined);
```

or also (to show the call with a single row):

```
$item = array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => 'Joe',
  2 => 'Bloggs',
  3 => 'joe.bloggs@mail.com',
  4 => '1,2',
  5 => 1,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 1,
);
$combined = combineArray($combined, $item);
```

The loop version works as expected with the following data:

```
$row = array(
array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => 'Joe',
  2 => 'Bloggs',
  3 => 'joe.bloggs@mail.com',
  4 => '1,2',
  5 => 1,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 1,
),array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => 'Joe',
  2 => 'Bloggs',
  3 => 'joe.bloggs@mail.com',
  4 => '1,2',
  5 => 0,
  6 => 1,
  7 => 1,
),array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => 'Jane',
  2 => 'Doe',
  3 => 'jane.doe@mail.com',
  4 => '1,4',
  5 => 1,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 1,
),array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => 'Jane',
  2 => 'Doe',
  3 => 'jane.doe@mail.com',
  4 => '1,4',
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
));
```

and outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Joe
            [2] => Bloggs
            [3] => joe.bloggs@mail.com
            [4] => 1,2
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Jane
            [2] => Doe
            [3] => jane.doe@mail.com
            [4] => 1,4
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. This didn't work for me. I got a fatal error: Error: Cannot use assign-op operators with string offsets in. I guess it's trying to add a string

Comment: @Fazberry my code works correctly with the data you supplied (I had tested it). If different data yields different results, you should post the data that you're actually using.

Could it be that you're using `$row` to indicate **a single component array** instead of `$item`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$res = array();

foreach($array as $vals){
    if(($index = array_search($vals[0], array_column( $res, 0))) !== false) {
        $res[$index][5] += $vals[5];
        $res[$index][6] += $vals[6];
        $res[$index][7] += $vals[7];
    } else {
        $res[] = $vals;
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Output with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Joe
            [2] => Bloggs
            [3] => joe.bloggs@mail.com
            [4] => 1,2
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Jane
            [2] => Doe
            [3] => jane.doe@mail.com
            [4] => 1,4
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
$rows = array(
        array (
            0 => '2',
            1 => 'Joe',
            2 => 'Bloggs',
            3 => 'joe.bloggs@mail.com',
            4 => '1,2',
            5 => 1,
            6 => 0,
            7 => 1,
        ),
        array (
            0 => '2',
            1 => 'Joe',
            2 => 'Bloggs',
            3 => 'joe.bloggs@mail.com',
            4 => '1,2',
            5 => 0,
            6 => 1,
            7 => 1,
        ),
        array (
            0 => '1',
            1 => 'Jane',
            2 => 'Doe',
            3 => 'jane.doe@mail.com',
            4 => '1,4',
            5 => 1,
            6 => 0,
            7 => 1,
        ),
        array (
            0 => '1',
            1 => 'Jane',
            2 => 'Doe',
            3 => 'jane.doe@mail.com',
            4 => '1,4',
            5 => 0,
            6 => 0,
            7 => 0,
        ));

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    if (isset($t[$row[3]])) {

        $t[$row[3]][5] += $row[5];
        $t[$row[3]][6] += $row[6];
        $t[$row[3]][7] += $row[7];
    } else 
        $t[$row[3]] = $row;
}

foreach ($t as $r) $combined[] = $r;

print_r($combined);
```

Comment: the problem is that the email or column 3 will be the key

Comment: ok then fill it in another array  `foreach ($combined as $r) $without[] = $r;

Comment: I've edit now my answer. If it does what you want. Please consider accepting. Thank you